# Why i = 1, and i = i + 1 would become 2?

Tags: python-3.x

```
i = 1
i = i + 1
print(i)
```

I am pretty confused about the code's logic. Why would `i` eventually become 2?

Answer (score 1):

'i' is a variable which stored 1 if We add 1 again in 'i' that means

i=1;

i+1 means 1+1=2

i=1
i=i+1// i has already 1 and here we are adding 1 again so result will be 2.

hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

Lets begin with the first assignment:

```
i = 1
```

This creates the variable `i` and initialize it to the integer value `1`.

Then we get to what you seem to have problem understanding:

```
i = i + 1
```

This statement can be split into two parts:

1. The addition
2. The assignment

The addition `i + 1` will take the current values of the variable `i`, which is `1`, and add the value `1` to that. In essence the expression `i + 1` is the same as `1 + 1`.

The result of the addition will be `2`. And this result is then assigned to the variable `i`, making the value of `i` be equal to `2`.

You then print the (new) current value of `i`:

```
print(i)
```

This will of course print the value `2`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that one modifies the data-structure itself (in-place operation) `b += 1` while the other just reassigns the variable `a = a + 1`.

Just for completeness:

`x += y` is not always doing an in-place operation, there are (at least) three exceptions:

If x doesn't implement an `__iadd__` method then the `x += y` statement is just a shorthand for x = x + y. This would be the case if x was something like an int

If `__iadd__` returns NotImplemented, Python falls back to `x = x + y.`

The `__iadd__` method could theoretically be implemented to not work in place. It'd be really weird to do that, though.

As it happens your bs are numpy.ndarrays which implements `__iadd__` and return itself so your second loop modifies the original array in-place.

You can read more on this in the Python documentation of "Emulating Numeric Types".

Comment: Way too trival.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from `i = 1`. So you are assigning `i` to 1. Now your situation is:

```
i = i + 1
```

So if `i` is 1, then the abovementioned code would be "translated" to:

```
i = 1 + 1
```

That's why `i = i + 1` is equal to 2.